# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeNavigation.default.push')

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I just updated RNN to version 2 and I'm stuck with my first push

I get an error :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeNavigation.default.push')
```

other answers on stack overflow didn't help me much so far

I guess my issue is related to `this.props.componentId` but I couldn't find any help in the official doc as well.

or perhaps it's coming from a wrong call to the stack since I never use the id property set in `App.js`

I'm also wondering if I have to provide an id manually for each screen or, as it is said in the doc it will be done automatically by RNN

if someone can guide me, I'm a bit lost -_-

my code :

**App.js**

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import LandingScreen from './src/screens/Landing/Landing';
import AuthScreen from './src/screens/Auth/Auth';

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

import strings from './src/global/strings';

const store = configureStore();

// Landing
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux(strings.screens.screenLanding, () => LandingScreen, Provider, store);

// Auth
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux(strings.screens.screenAuth, () => AuthScreen, Provider, store);


// Start App

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack:{
        id:"appStack",
        children: [
          {
            component: {
              name: strings.screens.screenLanding,
              options: {
                topBar:{
                  title:{
                    text:"Welcome"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },

    }
  });
});
```

**Landing.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

import Navigation from 'react-native-navigation';

import strings from '../../global/strings';

class Landing extends Component {

    goToScreen = (screenName) => {
        Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
            component: {
                name: screenName
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    title="Connexion"
                    onPress={() => this.goToScreen(strings.screens.screenAuth.toString())}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as indicated by **jinshin1013** in [RNN issue tracker](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4662) In Landing.js,

I should have import Navigation like this :

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation
```